# Problem in loading data in django database using 'loaddata'

Tags: django, django-views

I have done this in my views:

To serialize data I have done:

```
@login_required
@product_1_activation
def getcompanyObject(request, pk):
    company_details = get_object_or_404(company, pk=pk)
    all_objects = list(Company.objects.filter(pk=pk)) + list(Group1.objects.filter(Company=company_details.pk)) + list(Ledger1.objects.filter(Company=company_details.pk)) + list(Journal.objects.filter(Company=company_details.pk)) + 
    data = serializers.serialize('json', all_objects)
    data = json.dumps(json.loads(data), indent=4)
    response = HttpResponse(data , content_type='application/json')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={}-{}.json'.format(company_details.Name,datetime.now()) 
    return response
```

And then I tried:

```
from django.core.management import call_command

@login_required
def company_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_company = request.FILES['myfile']

        obj_generator = serializers.json.Deserializer(new_company)

        for obj in obj_generator:
            call_command('loaddata', obj, verbosity=0)

    return render(request, 'company/import.html')
```

Its similar to `python manage.py loaddata`.

But when I try to execute this I get the following error:

```
Problem installing fixture '<DeserializedObject: company': company(pk=87)> is not a known serialization format.
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?If there is any wrong in my code please help me to rectify my errors.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to save the file to disk first. The `loaddata` command expects the argument to be the path of a [fixture file](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#what-s-a-fixture) on disk.

You could save the uploaded file to a temp file and then call `loaddata` on it.

For example:

```
import tempfile
from django.core.management import call_command

@login_required
@product_1_activation
def company_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_company = request.FILES['myfile']

        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir='/tmp') as temp:
            for chunk in new_company.chunks():
                temp.write(chunk)
            call_command('loaddata', '/tmp/{}'.format(temp.name), verbosity=0)

    return render(request, 'company/import.html')
```

Comment: Its throwing me this error now `No fixture named 'tmpnxh2e_dq' found.` in this line of code `call_command('loaddata', temp.name, verbosity=0)`

Comment: It seems that `temp.name` on your system doesn't give the full path (it does on mine). I have updated the answer to use an explicit directory of `/tmp` - see if that works.